# Why can't set focus on element with nextElementSibling.focus() and parentNode.children[0].focus()?

Tags: javascript, nodes, keycode

I want to move mouse focus when keydown is `enter`,to emulate `enter` as `tab`.

```js
function  jump(event){
    var  ob = event.target;
    if(event.keyCode ==  13){
        if(ob.nextElementSibling){
            ob.nextElementSibling.focus();
        }
        else{
            ob.parentNode.children[0].focus();
        }
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",jump,true);
```

```html
content:<input id="1th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<textarea id="2th" cols=6 rows=5></textarea>
<br/>
content:<input id="3th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<input id="4th" type="text">
```

My expectation:
When you type some characters ,for example `test` in the `input` whose `id` is "1th",and press enter,the mouse focus jump into the `input` whose `id` is "2th".
When you type some characters ,for example `test` in the `input` whose `id` is "4th",and press enter,the mouse focus jump into the `input` whose `id` is "1th".

I tested my code ,no error info  occur,but it can't achieve my target.
How to fix it?

[image: breakpoint]

I have set breakpoint at the 23th line,still nothing found.

Comment: Because your `nextElementSibling` is a `<br />`.

Comment: I can change `ob.nextElementSibling.focus(); ` into `ob.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.focus();`,why `ob.parentNode.children[0].focus();` can't work?

Comment: It is ugly to write such expression as `ob.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.focus()`.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and checked what if `content:<input id="4th" type="text">` actually has a `nextElementSibling` ?

Comment: Please tell me how to set the breakpoint to chech what happened for `ob.parentNode.children[0].focus()`?

Comment: You can use debugger; within your code. If the developer console is open, execution will break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181130/discussion-between-scrapy-and-callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the chat with `callback`.

1.Format1:script is at the head ,add `window.onload`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
function  jump(event){
    var  ob = event.target;
    if(event.keyCode ==  13){
        if(ob.nextElementSibling != null){
            ob.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.focus();
        }
        else {
            ob.parentNode.children[0].focus();
        }
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",jump,true);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    content:<input id="1th" type="text">
    <br/>
    content:<textarea id="2th" cols=6 rows=5></textarea>
    <br/>
    content:<input id="3th" type="text">
    <br/>
    content:<input id="4th" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Format 2:script is put at the end of the last input whose id is `4th`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    content:<input id="1th" type="text">
    <br/>
    content:<textarea id="2th" cols=6 rows=5></textarea>
    <br/>
    content:<input id="3th" type="text">
    <br/>
    content:<input id="4th" type="text">
<script>
function  jump(event){
    var  ob = event.target;
    if(event.keyCode ==  13){
        console.log(ob.nextElementSibling.tagName);
        if(ob.nextElementSibling.tagName == "BR"){
            ob.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.focus();
        }
        else if(ob.nextElementSibling.tagName == "SCRIPT"){
            ob.parentNode.children[0].focus();
        }
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",jump,true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The whole code is position-related,different position of script's content in the html file,you should write different js code for that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the chat discussion, your issue is that the `nextElementSibling` in the `<br/>`. If you dont want to use `nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling`, There are two options that can help you here:

Either:

Remove the `<br>` and use CSS to add the necessary `margin-bottom`.

Or:

Add a class to your input/textArea elements and use jQuery with the function `.next('className')`. There are equivalents in Javascript but it will add a lot of unnecessary code.

I definitely recommend the first option than loading a whole library if the only use would be that one function.